# Simple variable question in PHP and XML

Tags: php, xml

I would like to add a variable `( $var )` inside the following code but I am having error...

```
$employee = $xml->addChild('XXXXXXX');
$employee->addChild('XXXXX', 'XXXXXX');
```

Any help would be great.
In addition how can i modify the first line so that I can add an attribute to it?
For example `<book ID="XXXX">`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addChild` takes a DOMNode as its argument, not text strings. You need to create the nodes and append them... for example:

```
//assuming $xml is a DOMDoucment

// <employee>XXX</employee>
$employee = $xml->createElement('employee', 'XXX');

// create an attribute node and a text nod to use for its value
$idNode = $xml->createAttribute('id');
$idValue = $xml->createTextNode('some-id');

// set the value of the attribute node
$idNode->appendChild($idValue);

// add the attribute to the element
$employee->appendChild($idNode);

// or more easily add an attribute
$employee->setAttribute('another', 'some-value');

// append the element to the document
$xml->appendChild($employee);

// final result:
// <root><employee id="some-id" another="some-value">XXX</employee></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds an attribute to the XML element:

```
    $xml->addAttribute("id","1234");
```